# Latex: using figure and caption in documentclass slides

Tags: slideshow

In `\documentclass[12pt]{slides}` I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{slides}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image}
\caption{W-labeled H-diagram \label{Fig:W-labeled-4-heap}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It displayed fine in an article I wrote, but not in slides. The `[h]` is displayed (which I've since removed and this works). Also, the caption is displayed next to the figure and no longer under it. The figure is displayed but does not match the size of the rest of the slides. Can you advise on how to adjust in a simple way, while still using slides?

Comment: Is there a reason for using `slides` rather than `beamer`?

Comment: Slides is what I use standard and I have set up matters for giving presentations. I don't need many frills, just a plain maths talk with figures. So if I can get a solution for figures and captions, matters are sorted. I don't have time to delve into beamer, but can visit at a later stage.

Comment: With the code you posted in your question I can not reproduce the output you describe. Could you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the output you currently get?

Comment: With the example as posted latex gives a clear warning that there is no `12pt` option to the class, and an error that the `figure` environment is not defined.  `slides` class does not support floats as there is no page breaking.